Comparing values of ClosedXML cells
I have been working on a program in VB.NET using ClosedXML. It basically should take in data from 2 Excel files.
Here is a sample of 1st (and only) worksheet from the first file (referred to as ws2):



First In Last Out








Employee   ID
Date
Weekday
First Check In
Last Check Out


10
2024-04-15
Monday

15:04


10
2024-04-16
Tuesday
08:46
14:41


10
2024-04-17
Wednesday
08:34



10
2024-04-18
Thursday
07:50
15:18


10
2024-04-20
Saturday
09:00
15:10


10
2024-04-21
Sunday
08:16
15:53


10
2024-04-22
Monday
08:41
15:22


10
2024-04-25
Thursday
08:05



10
2024-04-27
Saturday
08:10



10
2024-04-28
Sunday
07:27



10
2024-04-29
Monday
07:57
16:04


10
2024-04-30
Tuesday
07:40
15:32


101
2024-04-02
Tuesday
08:55
10:54



Here is a sample of the first (and only) worksheet from the 2nd file (referred to as ws3):







Sunday









Attendance
Leave


1
3
Ahmed
Management
8:30
14:05


2
4
Mark
Management
8:30
9:30


3
7
Michael
Financial
off
off



And Monday, Tuesday ... so on, it is a wide table that I did not post all of it.
My code is supposed to calculate the attendance from the fingerprint device file (ws2) and compare it to the actual time table file (ws3) for each employee, and create a new Excel file (referred to as ws xD) and copy all columns from ws3 into ws, and then make 3 new columns for the late / early leave / absence (I hadn't started with the absence part yet), and count how many late / early leave / absence every employee got and write in same row as his name and fingerprint (fp).
My problem is with the calculation process, here is the code I used:
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

        Dim wb1 As IXLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook("C:\Users\DelL\Downloads\Test\Test2.xlsx")
        Dim ws As IXLWorksheet = wb1.Worksheet(1)

        Dim wb2 As IXLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim ws2 As IXLWorksheet = wb2.Worksheet(1)
        ws2.Range("A:G").CopyTo(ws.Cell("A1"))

        Dim wb3 As IXLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim ws3 As IXLWorksheet = wb3.Worksheet(1)
        ws3.Range("A:N").CopyTo(ws.Cell("H1"))

        For index As Integer = 1 To 250
        Dim LateCount As Integer
        Dim EarlyLeaveCount As Integer
        LateCount = 0
        EarlyLeaveCount = 0
            For Each fingerprintCell In ws2.Cells
                For TotalFingerPrintsRows As Integer = 1 To ws2.RowsUsed.Count
                    If ws2.Cell("A" + TotalFingerPrintsRows).Value = index And ws2.Cell("C" + TotalFingerPrintsRows).Value = "Sunday" Then
                        For index2 As Integer = 1 To 1
                            For Each TimetableCell In ws3.Cells
                                For TotalTimetableRows As Integer = 1 + ws3.RowsUsed.Count
                                    If ws3.Cell("B" + TotalTimetableRows).Value = index Then
                                        If ws2.Cell("D" + TotalFingerPrintsRows).Value > ws3.Cell("E" + TotalTimetableRows).Value Then
                                            LateCount = +1
                                        End If
                                        If ws2.Cell("E" + TotalFingerPrintsRows).Value < ws3.Cell("F" + TotalTimetableRows).Value Then
                                            EarlyLeaveCount = +1
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Next
                            Next
                        Next
                    End If

And repeat for the next 4 days of the week
Problem is: I get an empty Excel file at location C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\Test\Test2.xlsx
While debugging, I get these errors

a syntax error for every RowsUsed.count function I used and I don't really understand how is it supped to be written

an error (Operator > (or <) is not defined for types XLCellValue and XLCellvalue) on lines like:
If ws2.Cell("E" + TotalFingerPrintsRows).Value < ws3.Cell("F" + TotalTimetableRows).Value Then




IMHO, you need a somewhat different approach to the problem. Any time you have more than three nested (for/while/etc.) loops, there is probably a better way of formulating a solution that will be much faster and easier to work with.
A database will be a better way of processing the data.
I suggest that you parse the data from strings into proper types, for example, datetime appears to be exactly what you need (combine the date and the time when you read the data), and store it in a database. Take some time to design the tables in the database—if there is a blank cell in the spreadsheet, how should it be represented in the database: would a NULL be appropriate, or should there be another column to indicate if there is a valid value in a particular column? And any other things like that which could happen. Don't store the day-of-week as a string, instead, use a calendar table (something else for you to investigate) if you need to convert from a date to a day-of-week.
Make sure to have a reliable backup for the data.

As for some of the problems stated in your question:-
First, make sure that Option Infer On and Option Strict On are set. Then you can use lines like Dim wb2 = New XLWorkbook(fileA) and Visual Studio will assign the correct type to the variable for you, in this case XLWorkBook.
Considering the comments on the answers to ClosedXML find last row number, did you mean ws2.RowsUsed.Count or ws2.LastRowUsed.RowNumber?
If you want to increment a value, it's LateCount += 1, not = +1.
For the comparison problem, it looks like some of the cells you want to compare could be empty or have text like "off". You will need to decide how to compare those to data such as 7:30. This would be part of the parsing to store the data in a database if you go with my recommended approach to the problem.

Hello .
thanks for your recommendation , i will consider this if this method "completely doesn't work", this is just a practice .
i turned the Option strict / Option Infer On . Problem number 1 seems to be already solver , the file is saved on the correct location with the right rows from ws2 and ws3 copied to it .
secondly , i did not really understand the difference between RowsUsed.Count / LastRowUsed.RowNumber , doesn't this return the same thing ?
yes thanks i adjusted the " += 1"

for the comparing problem , i want to ignore the empty cells , and logically there should be no comparing in "off" text cells since the employee will not have his fingerprint records in the file when it's his day off , and even if there were records i simply want it to be ignored and skip to the next cell .
i read about it and in my opinion using 'If ws2.Cells() IsNot Nothing Then'  would be the best option no ?  @Andrew Morton   link

i also noticed that i get the same error in lines like :
If ws3.Cell("B" + TotalTimetableRows).Value = index Then

@RodwanAlburie For checking if a cell has a value which can be parsed as a TimeSpan, you could use the TryGetValue method as listed in the API Reference for Cell.
